# Prevent Newline with Foundation Grid

Tags: html, zurb-foundation

I have a grid using Foundation as so:

```
<ul class="small-block-grid-1 medium-block-grid-3 large-block-grid-4">
    <li><img src='xxx.jpg'></li>
    <li><img src='xxx.jpg'></li>
    <li><img src='xxx.jpg'></li>
    ...
</ul>
```

I use jscroll to load the page as users scroll down. This adds a new `ul` each time, however this also means a new row is started whenever this occurs. Is it possible to get the following `ul` elements to continue on from the previous list?

Comment: no but why not load `<li>` tags instead of `<ul>`

Comment: using jscroll creates a `<div>` before the next set of `<li>`, causuing a newline to be created still. Is it possible to get this div to not create a new line?